# How to swap a 16bit Value with x86 Assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, swap

Hi I want to swap a 16 bit value.
In in an other question someone suggested the following solution.
But this only works with immidiate values,

```
mov  eax, 0AABBCCDDh
xchg  ah, al
ror   eax, 16
xchg  ah, al.
```

But this only works with immidiate values.
Is there a solution, where I can swap a 16 bit value which is in a register?

Edit:
   With swap I mean 0xAFBA -> 0xBAFA

Comment: What do you mean by swap - change endianness, i.e. switch high and low byte ?

Comment: The value is in a register after it's loaded.  So you actually have less work to do.  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: There's `bswap` for what you are doing above.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Ok but how do I get a register value in the eax?
 My problem is, that I need something like 
"mov eax, [other register]"
but I think it's only possible to move immidiate values like 0x0AABBCCDDh

Comment: Not true. You can move any 32-bit value to eax (or 16-bit value to ax), and back afterwards, if you want.

Comment: @R_Valdez: no - that's nonsense - you can just move one register to another, e.g. `mov eax, ebx`.

Comment: Did you really mean `0xAFBA -> 0xBAFA` or `0xBAAF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With swap I mean 0xAFBA -> 0xBAFA

```
mov   ax, 0xAFBA
xchg  al, ah
ror   al, 4
```

AX now holds 0xBAFA